# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null - I can see value in console.log()

Tags: javascript, html

The goal of this project is to develop a web app that can be used to fetch users from https://api.github.com/users and list their details along with repo information. I am having a problem with my `forEach()` in my `add_user_repos()` function. The function works on the first click but not the second. Below is my code for a web app. I am getting a error :

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null'
```

Error can be located at the end of the paste, next to comment `<== ERROR HERE`

I have used `console.log(repo.name)` and it prints.

Any feedback on the problem or my code in general will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="problem_3.css">



</head>
<body>
<div class="center">
    <div class="section">
        <form name="search_bar">
            <label for="search"></label>
            <input id="search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Username">
            <button type="button" onclick="search_user()">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>User Profile</h1>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="picture">
                <!-- image -->
            </div>
            <div id="user_info">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name: </th>
                        <td id="name"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Username: </th>
                        <td id="username"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Email: </th>
                        <td id="email"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Locations: </th>
                        <td id="location"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Number of gists: </th>
                        <td id="gists"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="container">
    <h1>User Repos</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="user_repos">
            <div class="user_repos">
                <table id="repo">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name: </th>
                        <td id="name0"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Description: </th>
                        <td id="desc0"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name: </th>
                        <td id="name1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="row">
                        <th>Description: </th>
                        <td id="desc1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name: </th>
                        <td id="name2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="row">
                        <th>Description: </th>
                        <td id="desc2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name: </th>
                        <td id="name3"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="row">
                        <th>Description: </th>
                        <td id="desc3"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name: </th>
                        <td id="name4"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="row">
                        <th>Description: </th>
                        <td id="desc4"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
    function search_user(){

        const url = 'https://api.github.com/users/';
        const name = document.forms["search_bar"]["search"].value;
        get_user_details(name);

        async function get_user_details(input){
            const headers = {
                //token
            }

            const resp = await fetch(url + input, {
                "method": "GET",
                "headers":headers
            });

            const data = await resp.json();
            addData(data);
        }

        function addData(data) {
            const user_name = document.getElementById("name");
            const user_username = document.getElementById("username");
            const user_email = document.getElementById("email");
            const user_location = document.getElementById("location");
            const user_picture = document.getElementById("picture");
            const user_gists = document.getElementById("gists");
            const pic = new Image();

            pic.src = data.avatar_url;
            user_picture.appendChild(pic);
            user_name.innerHTML = data.name;
            console.log(data.name);
            user_username.innerHTML = data.login;
            user_email.innerHTML = data.email;
            user_location.innerHTML = data.location;
            user_gists.innerHTML = data.public_gists;

            get_user_repos(data.login);

            async function get_user_repos(username) {
                const resp = await fetch(url + username + "/repos");
                const repo_data = await resp.json();
                add_user_repos(repo_data);
            }

            function add_user_repos(repos) {

                // counter used to find if more than 5 repos are added
                let counter = 0;

                const repo_div = document.getElementById("user_repos");

                repos.forEach((repo) => {
                    let repo_name = document.getElementById("name" + counter);
                    let repo_desc = document.getElementById("desc" + counter);

                    // if more than 5 repo names/desc are added
                    if (counter > 4) {
                        const create_repo_name = document.createElement("p");
                        const create_desc = document.createElement("p");

                        create_repo_name.innerHTML = "<b>Name: </b>" + repo.name;
                        create_desc.innerHTML = "<b>Description: </b>" + repo.description;
                        create_desc.setAttribute("class", "row");
                        repo_div.appendChild(create_repo_name);
                        repo_div.appendChild(create_desc);

                        // add scrolling
                        document.getElementById("user_repos").style.overflow = "auto";
                    } else {
                        repo_name.innerHTML = repo.name; // <== ERROR HERE
                        repo_desc.innerHTML = repo.description;
                        repo_name.setAttribute("id", "row" + counter);
                        repo_desc.setAttribute("id", "desc" + counter);
                        counter++;
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: you are renaming your ids, for the next search you are NOT using those renamed id's thereby introducing a big problem.. You need a reset function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the node element to have an id of "row"+ counter

`repo_name.setAttribute("id", "row" + counter);`

set it to have an id of "name" + counter

`repo_name.setAttribute("id", "name" + counter);`

Thereby in the next searches you will again be able to find that element in the DOM.

Comment: It was as simple as that, cant believe I didn't see it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null'
```

The issue is related to `repo_name` variable, not `repo.name`.

`document.getElementById("name" + counter);` returns null

You should ensure `"name" + counter` exists in your DOM.